# Access class instance from one file in another file?

Tags: python, class, instance

I have two files, both are in the same project (part of a web scraping framework).  File1 processes items that are generated by File2.  In File2 I have a function that prints out some basic stats about the processes (counts of how many items have been generated, etc).  I have counts in File1 that I would like to print with the stats from File1 but am unsure of how to do that.  Take a look at the example code.

FILE 1:

```
class Class1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stats = counter("name") #This is the instance that I'd like to use in File2
        self.stats.count = 10

class counter:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.count = 0
    def __string__(self):
        message = self.name + self.count
        return message
```

FILE 2: (this is what I'd like to do)

```
from project import file1 # this import returns no error

def stats():
    print file1.Class1.stats # This is where I'm trying to get the instance created in Class1 of File2.
    #print file1.Class1.stats.count # Furthermore, it would be nice if this worked too.
```

ERROR:

```
exceptions.AttributeError: type object 'Class1' has no attribute 'stats'
```

I know that both files are running, thus so does the 'stats' instance of the 'counter' class, because of other methods being printed out when running the project (this is just a stripped down example.  What am I doing wrong here?  Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not working because you never instantiate `Class1`.

`__init__` is called when the `Class1` is instantiated so `Class1.stats` is set.

You have 2 options here.

1. instantiate `Class1` in file 2 somehow.
2. declare a static method in `Class1` that returns the count property.

Answer (score 4):

In File1, create an instance of Class1, and use that to get the count.

```
class Class1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stats = counter()
        self.stats.count = 10

class counter:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.count = 0
    def __string__(self):
        message = self.name + self.count
        return message

class_instance = Class1()
```

In file2, use the created instance:

```
from project import file1

def stats():
    print file1.class_instance.stats
```

Answer (score 4):

Your terminology is a little mixed up. *"both files are running, thus so does the 'stats' instance of the 'counter' class"* - `stats` is a attribute of *objects* of the `counter` class. If you want a count of how many instances of the class are created, you should use a *class attribute* which is something that is bound to your class, and not an instance of it.

```
class Counter(object):
    count = 0

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        Counter.count += 1
        self.id = Counter.count

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Counter: %s (%d of %d)>' % (
            self.name, self.id, Counter.count)
```

So then this can be used like so,

```
>>> foo = Counter('Foo')
>>> print foo
<Counter: Foo (1 of 1)>
>>> bar = Counter('Bar')
>>> print bar
<Counter: Bar (2 of 2)>
>>> print foo
<Counter: Foo (1 of 2)>
>>>
```

Note that the second time you `print foo` it has updated the count, but the `id` remains the same, that is because `count` is a class attribute, but `id` is an attribute of the object, so (with this code) the creation of `bar` doesn't affect the `id` of `foo`, but it increments `Counter.count`.